# Relationship between a set and a graph

Tags: math, graph, set

I am trying to know whether these are related
(Both mathematics and programming)

wikipedia says:

> a graph is a structure amounting to a set of objects in which some
>   pairs of the objects are in some sense "related."

It looks like graph is somewhat related to sets.
Is it a relation in set theory?

Comment: A graph is usually defined by sets (but there are other ways too). Which kind of sets? That depends on the graph (e.h. multiset -> hypergraph). Why studying this? And you should know that this question is really not fitted for SO (and against the rules).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was studing C++ STL. The book says they are collections and I was wondering if there are some similarity between set, graph and trees.

Answer (score 1):

A graph is a collection of nodes (points). Each node can be connected to any other node and the connections can be directed or undirected.

I don't know if there is a 'generic' implementation of a graph, but I would implement it like:
- Nodes: collection (either list, array, depending on the characteristics)
- Per node: Connections: collection of Connection
- Connection: one connection, undirected connections will be implemented as two connections, one from each node. It can also be implemented as a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

A **Set**- is a Mathematical concept. For example, a set of even natural numbers.

--> A set can be *empty*, *countable*, *uncountable*, *finite* or *infinite*, etc.

---

A **Graph** is a representation of one or several sets. If members of your set are in some kind of a relationship, then you can represent your set as a graph. For example, a set of Facebook users can be represented in a (extremely large) graph where nodes are users, and presence of an edge between two nodes says that those users are friends.

--> A graph can be *connected*, *disconnected*, *cyclic*, *acyclic*, *Hamiltonian*, etc.

---

A **Tree** is a particular type of graphs which do not contain any cycles.

--> A tree can be *rooted* or not, *binary*, *ternary*, ..., *ordered*, etc.